# Google Script Editor getRange issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Thank you to anyone that can help.

I'm trying to scan through column B on my spreadsheet for the word 'default shipping' and send myself an email with the person's email which is located in column F which is under 'range.getRow(), 6' and works fine. I know this works as I have successfully sent myself an email when I use 'getActiveCell' instead of 'sheet.getRange(2,2,700,2)' and select the cell that contains 'default shipping'

I've tried all different methods, but I'm stuck and I'm not sure if I need to create loop but if I could avoid this, this will be most beneficial.

Here is the code which I've copied but made some changes to suit my needs.

```
function sendemail() {

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Sheet1";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 2; 
  var valueToWatch = "Default shipping";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,2,700,2); // this is my problem

  var email = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 6).getValue();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var emailAddress = "my@email.com";
    var subject = "Default Shipping Alert";
    var email = "Please check the order and contact customer if necesary by clicking this link! www.website.com/search:"+email+"";

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, email);
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need a loop. You should review the official "best practices" documentation for Apps Script and also how to work with 2D JavaScript arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use a for-loop. I have cleaned the code a little bit and made a few modifications. The flow of the script is described below:

1. The sheet that you are watching ("Sheet1") is obtained using [`getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getSheetByName(String)).
2. From the obtained sheet, two ranges are obtained: `columnB`, which holds the shipping status and `emails` for the email addresses. Both of them are equal in size (700 rows) and order.
3. For each record in `columnB`, the shipping status is checked. In case it matches `valueToWatch`, an email is generated and sent to its matching address in the `emails` array.

Additionally, the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is used when generating the email's body. That is to make sure that the final URL is valid and conforms the standards.

```js
function sendemail() {

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Sheet1";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 2; 
  var valueToWatch = "Default shipping";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetNameToWatch);
  var columnB = sheet.getRange(2, columnNumberToWatch, 700, 1).getValues();
  var emails = sheet.getRange(2, 6, 700, 1).getValues();

  for (var i=0; i<columnB.length; i++) {
    if (columnB[i] == valueToWatch) {
      var emailAddress = emails[i];
      var subject = "Default Shipping Alert";
      var emailBody = "Please check the order and contact customer if necesary by clicking this link! www.website.com/search:"+encodeURIComponent(emailAddress);

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailBody);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a treat! Thank you so much! Although, I didn't want the email sent to the email address in row F. No big deal as this was easy enough to change as I just added my personal email in `var emailAddress = "My@email.com"` and swapped out  `emailAddress` at the end of `var emailBody` and swapped it for `emails[i]`. My bad if I wasn't clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendemail() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange(); 
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if (r[1]="Default shipping") {
      var emailAddress = "my@email.com";
      var subject = "Default Shipping Alert";
      var msg = "Please check the order and contact customer if necesary by clicking this link! www.website.com/search:"+r[5];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, msg);
    }
  });
}
```